# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in PostsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've started learning Ruby on Rails.

Iam getting below error: `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in PostsController#create`

**Here is the code:**

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find params[:id]
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post =  Post.create(params[:post]) // Its showing me error here

    if @post.save
      redirect_to posts_path notice: "Your Post was saved"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1> Add a New Post </h1>

<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><b/>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><b/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :content %><b/>
    <%= f.text_area :content %><b/>
  </p>
    <%= f.submit "Add a New Post" %>
<%  end %>
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title, :content
end
```

Please tell me what went wrong. BTW, iam using Rails4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In rails4 there is strong parameters so you can't do this:

```
@post =  Post.create(params[:post])
```

You need

```
@post =  Post.create(post_params)
```

Where `post_params` is a method in your controller:

```
private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit!
end
```

`permit!` will permit anything.  You can limit it though to what you want to allow for example `params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)`

Answer (score 6):

You have to use strong params for rails 4 to solve this problem.

Docs: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
end
```

and in create action use: `Post.create(post_params)`

You have to use strong params always when you create or update a record.